# How to re-skin a website at the client end?

Tags: browser, overriding, client-side, skinning

Any ways to re-skin a website (at the client end) where the format and layout of the page is mostly known and constant?

For example, changing the language of a certain form on eBay to Japanese.

I know that with Opera and Firefox a website's CSS can be overridden. Are there any ways in any browsers or browser plugins to override *text* and words on a certain page of a certain website?

Some of my ideas:

- browser plugin
- xslt / xPath etc

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a combination of CSS and using Greasemonkey (userscripts, in JavaScript) to change styles *as well as* change content. Greasemonkey & userscripts are supported by Firefox (by plugin) and Chrome (natively).

Comment: Thanks! Greasemonkey seems to be a very capable - yet programmatic - way to do what I want. I did actually have a more point-and-click vision in mind where I could click the element whose text I wanted to change and then type in the replacement text. Oh well, guess I'll have to write that one myself!